# Set id to dynamic created spantag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

ive got this code:

```
  @foreach (var field in Model.RiskScoreContent)
            {

                <div class="headriskscore">

                    <span class="statictext">@Html.DisplayFor(_ => field.QuestionString)</span>
                    <span class="fieldvalues">@Html.DisplayFor(_ => field.FieldValues)</span>
                    <span>@Html.DisplayFor(_=>field.Prefix) </span>

                </div>
            }
```

it goes through a loop and i want it to set the id of the field for every loop like so:
@Html.DisplayFor(_ => field.FieldValues)

and there is a id for every field in model.riskscorecontent that is called if i type model.fieldid but i cant set it in the span tag so how can i do this?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not clear what you want. You must set an id for the 2nd span (`FieldValues`) based on your model?

Comment: Can you please post the definition of `RiskScoreContent` ?

Comment: i want to set the id of my second span fieldvalue to a specific value that comes within the loop. like the value field.fieldvalue is reached from a list i want the id to be reached field.fieldid and i want the second span-tag to get that id

Comment: riskscorecontent is my list in my model. In the list there is values like fieldvalue, questionstring and fieldid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<span class="statictext" id="@model.fieldid">@Html.DisplayFor(_ => field.QuestionString)</span>
```

or

```
<span class="statictext" id="@field.fieldvalue">@Html.DisplayFor(_ => field.QuestionString)</span>
```

Comment: Exactly what i wanted! Thanks!:)